# making old keys the values for a new dictionary with list comprehension

Tags: python

I am trying to make a new list of dictionaries using list comprehension. I have an old list that has 'age' and 'email' keys, with their associated values. I am wanting to create a new list of dictionaries, where 'age' and 'email' are the VALUES of new keys called 'new_age', and 'new_email'.

How would I accomplish this?

```
entries = [{'age': 65, 'name': 'Tim', 'email': 'tim@bob.com'},{'age': 72, 'name': 'Andy', 'email': 'andy@bob.com'},{'age': 50, 'name': 'Bob', 'email': 'bob@bob.com'}, {'age': 30, 'name': 'Shelly', 'email': 'shelly@shelly.com'}]

x =[{dictionary['new_age'],dictionary['new_email']} for dictionary in entries if dictionary['age'] >= 50]
```

so my new list of dictionaries 'x' is supposed to make a new list of dictionaries if 'age' >= 50, and then I want just the 'age' and 'email' of that entry in a new dictionary.

so the form will look like this

```
[{'new_age': 65, 'new_email': bob@bob.com}, {}, etc]
```

my x list is just an example and it prints out the email, and age if age is above 50 but I need the key pairs in there as well, and this is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{dictionary['new_age'],dictionary['new_email']}` creates a *set*, not a *dictionary* (and it wouldn't work anyway because `dictionary`, which is an element of `entries`, doesn't contain the keys `new_age` and `new_email`)

To create a dictionary, you need key-value pairs like so:

```
[
    {'new_email': dictionary['email'], 'new_age': dictionary['age']} 
    for dictionary in entries if dictionary['age'] >= 50
]
```

which gives what you're looking for:

```
[{'new_email': 'tim@bob.com', 'new_age': 65},
 {'new_email': 'andy@bob.com', 'new_age': 72},
 {'new_email': 'bob@bob.com', 'new_age': 50}]
```

Comment: see my problem was, I was so fixed that dictionary['age'], dictionary['email'] was right, I didn't look at changing that....

Comment: Glad to help! Debugging is a very important skill to develop when you're learning to program, so I encourage you to read [How to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and inspect the results of your program. In your case, `x` would come out to be a list of sets, which is pretty clearly visible if you use a nice environment that lets you inspect your variables, like `spyder`. It can be helpful to write out your loops instead of going straight to comprehensions when you're a beginner because full loops are easier to think through and debug.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to fix how you're doing the dictionary comprehension

```py
x = [
    {'new_age': dictionary['age'], 'new_email': dictionary['email']}
    for dictionary in entries if dictionary['age'] >= 50
]
```