# How to add a new key to an existing dictionary and append previous key as value to the new key created in a for loop : python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a json format data in a list like below:-

```
lis_t=[{'score': 76, 'steps': [{'score': 49, 'len': 261}, {'score': 27, 'len': 172}, {'score': 0, 'len': 0}]},
{'score': 82,'steps': [{'score': 82, 'len': 484}, {'score': 0, 'len': 0 }]}, 
{'score': 51, 'steps': [{'score': 51, 'len': 268}, {'score': 0, 'len': 0},{'score': 16, 'len': 75}, {'score': 187, 'len': 47}]}]
```

From this list I want to add a new key `details` in the value of key `steps` and append only the `score` key as a `value` to the new key. The output I am excepting is as follow:-

```
    output =[{'score': 76, 'steps': [{'details':{'score': 49}, 'len': 261,'details': {'score': 27}, 'len': 172,'details': {'score': 0}, 'len': 0}]},
{'score': 82, 'steps': [{'details':{'score': 82}, 'len': 484, 'details':{'score': 0}, 'len': 0 }]}, 
{'score': 51, 'steps': [{'details':{'score': 51}, 'len': 268,'details': {'score': 0}, 'len': 0,'details':{'score': 16}, 'len': 75, 'details':{'score': 187}, 'len': 47}]}]
```

Now, I tried to create a new key `details` and tried to append the `value` but it says that the `dictionary size is changed while iterating`. To avoid this I have used list`(j.keys())` but if I use this then I wont be able to access the value of that dictionary. Is there any better way of solving this issue?

```
for i in lis_t:
    for k,v  in i.items():
        if k == 'steps':
            for j in v:
                for key,val in j.items():
                    j['details']=val
                    print(key)
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Excepted Output:-

```
    output=[{'score': 76, 'steps': [{'details':{'score': 49}, 'len': 261,'details': {'score': 27}, 'len': 172,'details': {'score': 0}, 'len': 0}]},
{'score': 82, 'steps': [{'details':{'score': 82}, 'len': 484, 'details':{'score': 0}, 'len': 0 }]}, 
{'score': 51, 'steps': [{'details':{'score': 51}, 'len': 268,'details': {'score': 0}, 'len': 0,'details':{'score': 16}, 'len': 75, 'details':{'score': 187}, 'len': 47}]}]
```

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, I think you are asking for something similar to what I asked. I think this could best be tackled with a list comprehension. Does my post help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68717392/making-old-keys-the-values-for-a-new-dictionary-with-list-comprehension

Comment: Your desired output has invalid syntax and is not really possible in python. You have list items that have keys. Lists use indexes. So you might want to change those lists to dicts or rearrange how you are storing the 'len' data.

Comment: Please provide correct output format(Requirement), Provided format is not correct

Comment: `for a in lis_t: for b in a['steps']: b['details'] = {'score': b.pop('score')}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a list comprehension to reset the "steps" value.  Maybe something like:

```
lis_t = [
    {
        'score': 76,
        'steps': [
            {'score': 49, 'len': 261},
            {'score': 27, 'len': 172},
            {'score': 0, 'len': 0}
        ]
    },
    {
        'score': 82,
        'steps': [
            {'score': 82, 'len': 484},
            {'score': 0, 'len': 0 }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        'score': 51,
        'steps': [
            {'score': 51, 'len': 268},
            {'score': 0, 'len': 0},
            {'score': 16, 'len': 75},
            {'score': 187, 'len': 47}
        ]
    }
]

for item in lis_t:
    item["steps"] = [
        {"details": {"score": step_item["score"]}, "len": step_item["len"]}
        for step_item in item["steps"]
    ]

import json
print(json.dumps(lis_t))
```

This gives:

```
[
    {
        "score": 76,
        "steps": [
            {"details": {"score": 49}, "len": 261},
            {"details": {"score": 27}, "len": 172},
            {"details": {"score": 0}, "len": 0}
        ]
    },
    {
        "score": 82,
        "steps": [
            {"details": {"score": 82}, "len": 484},
            {"details": {"score": 0}, "len": 0}
        ]
    },
    {
        "score": 51,
        "steps": [
            {"details": {"score": 51}, "len": 268},
            {"details": {"score": 0}, "len": 0},
            {"details": {"score": 16}, "len": 75},
            {"details": {"score": 187}, "len": 47}
        ]
    }
]
```

Which is what I think you are after.

Comment: Thanks Alot that was so simple